# Is poolEnrich loading the entire file content in memory?

Tags: apache-camel

I have a simple route like:

```
from("direct:fooBar")
 .pollEnrich()
 .simple("file:in/?fileName=abc.txt")
 .process(exchange -> {
          // 1
          exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
 })
 .split(body().tokenize("\n")).streaming().stopOnException()
 .process(exchange -> {
          // 2
          exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
  })
```

`abc.txt` it's a really huge file, so I'm using `split` and `streaming` to reduce memory overhead. 
But I'm able to grab file content at `1`, so I guess that the entire content is actually loaded into memory when using `poolEnrich`.

Is my assumption correct ?

Comment: for streaming a file you need to prepend `stream:` isn't is? like this `stream:file:in/?fileName=abc.txt`

Comment: @pvpkiran I just want to know if the provided example loads file content into memory and only after that starts splitting and streaming

Comment: what I meant is since you are not using stream to load the file, I believe it loads the whole file

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No `pollEnrich` does NOT load the entire file into memory. The file endpoint just gives you a file handle to the file, eg a `java.io.File`.

Its your code in the processor that loads the file into memory, when you tell Camel to convert the message body as a `String`. Then Camel will load the `java.io.File` into memory and give you its content as a `String`.

So instead of a `String` you can use `InputStream` if you want to read the body in a streaming fashion.

The splitter with the tokenizer will use `java.util.Scanner` to read chunks of the file and process that chunk by chunk. So that would work with the file endpoint and read it via a `FileInputStream`.

So remove your own code where you get the message body as a `String` and it ought to not load the entire file into memory.